# Log all Cloud Endpoint Request with request data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to log all Google Cloud Endpoints request on a Python App Engine.
The standard logging mechanism only logs that a request happened, but not the data or the header.

Is there a possibility to log these data automatically, or do I have to stick with manually logging the data for every request?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
import logging

@endpoints.api(args)
class YourApi(remote.Service):
    """Your API
    """
    @endpoints.method(args)
    def a_method(self, request):
        logging.info(request)
```

[Documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging)

Comment: This is actually what I meant, when I said, that I don't want to log the data manually for every request. (imagine an API with many request methods).